# Como centrar un div completamente? html, css

Tags: html, css, vue.js

Estoy creando una tabla que quiero que vaya en el centro de la pagina a la hora de mostrar la informacion,pero por alguna razon no se centra, esta asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en la esquina de la pagina y no se mueve,

aqui les muestro el codigo html:

```
<div id="see_actual_products">
       <section class = "see_actual_products_section">
            <div id="products">
                <h1 v-if="showProducts == true">{{message}}</h1>
            </div>
            <table id="table_container_actual_products">
                <tr>
                    <th v-bind:colspan = "length" >Actual products in making.</th>
                </tr>  
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table id ="table_actual_products" v-for="i in listCurrentproducts">
                            <caption> {{i.room}}</caption>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    Name:
                                    {{i.name}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                    LOT:
                                    {{i.lot}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>    
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                    Quantity to be package:
                                    {{i.quantity_to_package}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>    
                                <td>
                                    Quantity of pallets: 
                                    {{i.pallets}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr> 
                                <td>
                                    Progress:
                                    {{i.progress}}
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    {{i.finished_pallets}} pallets of {{i.pallets}} pallets
                                    <button @click="addPallet(i.room)">Add Pallet</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr v-if="i.pallets == i.finished_pallets">
                                <td>
                                    <h3>Completed</h3>
                                    <button @click="finish(i.room)">Finish procedure</button>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </td>    
                </tr> 
            </table>
        </section>
    </div>
```

el id see_actual_products lo uso solamente para Vuejs, el contenedor que estoy usando para centrar completamente es el section "see_actual_products_section", pero como dije anteriormente no me lo centra, aqui el codigo css:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}

.see_actual_products_section{
margin: auto;
padding: 20px;
border-radius: 4px;}
```

he buscado y dicen de usar text-aling:center pero solo centra los textos dentro de section, float, igual, gracias :)

Answer (score 3):

Utiliza flexbox en un div padre y luego centralo de forma vertical u horizontal, por ejemplo aqui te muestro como centro un cuadro rojo sobre un cuadro negro.

```css
.padre {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  /* Codigo para centrar*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  /* Fin del codigo para centrar*/
}

.hijo {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo">
  </div>
</div>
```